# php forum outputs string of text, how to find source of said string?

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a site which is a simple php forum, and every so often it'll insert an alert/error div on the page, e.g., "Error! You can't do that because of this," or whatever.

How do I search each of the files on my server for the string "Error! You can't do that because of this"? Asked differently, how do I find the source of the various errors when they arise, you know, without having to manually look at every single .php file on the server; thanks.

Comment: Get  decent editor that should have a search in file function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the command console, use GREP.

To search for `"Error! You can't do that because of this"` in all PHP files in a directory,

```
$ grep "Error! You can't do that because of this" ~/*.php
```

To search all subdirectories recursively,

```
$ grep -R "Error! You can't do that because of this" /
```

Comment: ^^The above, combined with this: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12333/how-to-grep-or-find-on-cpanel solved it for me; thanks.